# shinyFileSave does not save plots

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to save the generated plots of a shiny app to the server side and even though I got it working for the data frames it doesn't work for plots. Here is a snippet of the code that generates the plots but doesn't save the plots to the server side.

Here is the code on the `ui.R`

```
shinySaveButton(id = 'downloadplot1', label =  'Save plot', title = "Save plot as...", filetype = "png")
```

And here is the relevant code in the `server.R` script

```
observe({
    volumes <- c("wd"="/Users/upendra_35/Documents/CyVerse/Images_apps/DE/VICE/Ballgown_shinyapp/")
    shinyFileSave(input, "downloadplot1", roots=volumes, session=session)
    fileinfo <- parseSavePath(volumes, input$downloadplot1)
    if (nrow(fileinfo) > 0) {
      plotMeans(gene=input$gv_var_input, gown=bg1(), as.character(fileinfo$datapath))
    }
  })
```

Please let me know if you need to look at the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I figured it out. Here is how it worked..

```
observe({
    volumes <- c("wd"="/Users/upendra_35/Documents/CyVerse/Images_apps/DE/VICE/Ballgown_shinyapp/")
    shinyFileSave(input, "downloadplot1", roots=volumes, session=session)
    fileinfo <- parseSavePath(volumes, input$downloadplot1)
    if (nrow(fileinfo) > 0) {
      ggsave(plotMeans(gene=input$gv_var_input, gown=bg1()), filename = as.character(fileinfo$datapath))
    }
  })
```